# Bluetooth BLE readCharacteristic has some error

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

When I use BLE to read the characteristics of the time there are some errors,

**Error as follows：**

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED permission: Neither user 10168 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED.
```

But I've alredy added appropriate permissions：

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
```

Comment: characteristic.getProperties()=26 I dont not how it come.others equal 6 or 10

Comment: Just an idea: Is this characteristic protected, so that only paired devices can access it?

Comment: I have paired the device.As if only the system bluetooh can access it .
We try to use HID to communicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED in your manifest, but are you sure it was granted? According to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED "This is not available to third party applications"